# Result source query difference between SPSiteUrl and Site

Tags: 2013, search, query, result-source

Working with with result sources and sometimes I see the query like this:

`{searchTerms?} (contentclass:sts_listitem OR IsDocument:True) **SPSiteUrl**:https://example {?owstaxidLSTopic:{Tag}}`

And other times like this

`{searchTerms?} (contentclass:sts_listitem OR IsDocument:True) **Site**:https://example {?owstaxidLSTopic:{Tag}}`

I can't figure out what the difference is between the two. I found [this blog](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/spsiteurl-sharepoint-2013/) on the introduction of SPSiteUrl, but it doesn't address queries specifically.

Can anyone point me to a better resources that explains the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All out of the box Search Crawled and Managed Properties are listed in this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219630(v=office.15).aspx msdn article

To answer your question

- SPSiteUrl is mapped to ows_SPSiteURL
- Site is mapped to urn:schemas.microsoft.com:fulltextqueryinfo:sitename

Comment: Thank you that is helpful--for a bunch of things. So any idea what is different between those two properties?

Comment: I believe one is for SiteUrl and the other for Site Name. You can test this by changing the search query.